# Count Combinations with Repetition

Tags: binomial-distribution

When rolling 8 sided dice 20 times, what is the probability that you will roll 6 or more 1's (assuming that the sides are numbered 1 through 8)?

Please go easy on me as it's been decades since I studied statistics. After Googling a couple of hours, all I came up with was Excel's COMBA() function, but it only has two inputs. I also tried writing a Python script that tried to simulate all the different combinations and add up the totals. But that brute force method was trying to process 8^20 different combinations! After letting it run for about 5 hours, I pulled the plug on it.

How would you go about describing the problem and calculating the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Binomial distribution.** Rolls of the die are independent. Consider `1` to be a Success, which means the Success probability is $p = 1/8.$ So the number $X$ of `1`'s in $n = 20$ rolls of an eight-sided die has
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 20, p = 1/8).$

You can use the formula for the [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) PMF (or PDF) to find
$P(X \ge 6) = 1 - P(X \le 5),$ where the latter probability
involves summing six terms:

$$P(X \le 5) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) + \cdots + P(X=5),$$
where $P(X = k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$

Because you mention using a computer program to solve this
problem, I will show some approaches in that direction using R statistical software.
In R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, $P(X \ge 6) = 0.0312$ can be found as shown below:

```
1 - pbinom(5, 20, 1/8)
[1] 0.03116797
```

**Simulation.** The following R code simulates a million
'games', each with 20 rolls of an eight-sided die and counts how many `1`'s occur in each game. (The `sample` function simulates rolling the die.) With a million iterations, the simulated result should be accurate to
a couple of decimal places.

```
set.seed(505)
x = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(1:8, 20, rep=T)==1))
mean(x >= 6)
[1] 0.031227     # aprx P(X >= 6) = 0.03116797
2*sd(x >= 5)/1000
[1] 0.0008728716 # aprx 95% margin of sim error
```

The vector `x >= 5` is a logical vector of `TRUE`s and
`FALSE`s; its mean is the proportion of its `TRUE`s

**Graph.** Here is a graph of the relevant binomial distribution.
The desired probability is the heights of the bars to
the right of the vertical broken line. (Probabilities for more than about 8 are too small to see at the resolution of this plot.

[image]

R code for making the plot:

```
x = 0:20;  pdf = dbinom(x, 20, 1/8)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=2, col="blue", 
     main="PDF of BINOM(20, 1/8)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 5.5, col="red", lty="dashed")
```